# Async/await in ES6 class: await will not resolve and stays a Promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

My `await` in `initalize` does not get called and I don't know why:

I have a React class that acts as the entry point:

```
export const HulaHoop = React.createClass({ 
    async parseData(objects){
        return await parser(objects)
    }
});
```

which calls the `parser` function that creates instances of `MyClass`:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    async initialize(obj){
        this.field = await getField(obj);
        console.log(this.field) // <--- <Promise>
    }

    static async create(obj) {
        const myInstance = new MyClass(obj);
        await myInstance.initialize(obj);
        return myInstance;
  }
}

export async function getField(obj) {
    const d2 = await getInstance();
    let route = 'someField/' + obj.field;
    return await d2.get(route);
}

export default async function parser(objects) {
    let classes = [];
    for (let obj of objects) {
        let myclass = await MyClass.create(obj)
        classes.push(myclass)
    }
    return classes
}
```

Since the (final) class creation happens asynchronously, there is a `static async create()` method in place to initialize the Class. `Initalize` can never finish because it's waiting for the Async callback. How can I resolve so that `this.field` is actually resolved?

**Edit: it's the Jest testing that fails:**

```
test('parsing', async () => {
    let objects = await readCSV('file.csv');
    let res = await parser(objects); // waits forever in MyClass.create(obj)
    const expected = [ ... ]
    expect(data).toEqual(res);
}
```

Comment: how does `getInstance` look? have you tried to debug with step by step and breakpoints?

Comment: ok, the actual implementation works but my Jest unit testing is failing when waiting in the `parser` object - it waits forever on `await MyClass.create(obj)`

Comment: off topic: you can run the requests in paralell `export default async function parser(objects) { return Promise.all(objects.map(MyClass.create)) }` and `return await` *(in an async function)* is as pointless as `somePromise.then(value => value)`. Simply return the promise